# What's the difference between scan and match on Ruby string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am new to Ruby and has always used `String.scan` to search for the first occurrence of a number. It is kind of strange that the returned value is in nested array, but I just go `[0][0]` for the values I want. (I am sure it has its purpose, just that I haven't used it yet.)

I just found out that there is a `String.match` method. And it seems to be more convenient because the returned array is not nested.

Here is an example of the two, first is scan:

```
>> 'a 1-night stay'.scan(/(a )?(\d*)[- ]night/i).to_a
=> [["a ", "1"]]
```

then is match

```
>> 'a 1-night stay'.match(/(a )?(\d*)[- ]night/i).to_a
=> ["a 1-night", "a ", "1"]
```

I have check the API, but I can't really differentiate the difference, as both referred to 'match the pattern'.

This question is, for simply out curiousity, about what `scan` can do that `match` can't, and vise versa. Any specific scenario that only one can accomplish? Is `match` the inferior of `scan`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Short answer: `scan` will return all matches. This doesn't make it superior, because if you only want the first match, `str.match[2]` reads much nicer than `str.scan[0][1]`.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > 'a 1-night stay, a 2-night stay'.scan(/(a )?(\d*)[- ]night/i).to_a
 => [["a ", "1"], ["a ", "2"]] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > 'a 1-night stay, a 2-night stay'.match(/(a )?(\d*)[- ]night/i).to_a
 => ["a 1-night", "a ", "1"]
```

Comment: is part of reason that the search pattern contains group ? because for simple scan `str.scan(/\d+/)`, it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 26):

`#scan` returns everything that the Regex matches.

`#match` returns the first match as a [`MatchData`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/MatchData.html) object, which contains data held by special variables like `$&` (what was matched by the Regex; that's what's mapping to index 0), `$1` (match 1), `$2`, et al.

Answer (score 9):

Previous answers state that scan will return every match from the string the method is called on but this is incorrect

the string class' scan method iterates over a string and returns non overlapping matches

```
string = 'xoxoxo'

p string.scan('xo') # => ['xo' 'xo' 'xo' ]
# so far so good but...

p string.scan('xox') # => ['xox']
# if this retured EVERY instance of 'xox' it would include a substring
# starting at indices 0 and 2 but only one match is returned
```

Comment: Coming in 9 years later with additional info that improves upon the other answers. +1

Comment: This is incorrect. `scan` only returns nonoverlapping matches, so `'xoxoxo'.scan('xox')` also returns only a single match. It is the `StringScanner` class, not `String`, that has a current position that advances every time you call the `scan` method.

Comment: My answer was worded awkwardly. I was trying to describe how I believed the non overlapping matching behavior of string.scan works. I've improved my answer, cheers.