# Regex confusion

Tags: ruby, regex

Why one regex behaves differently for scan and match methods?

```
str = "A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama"

/\w+/.match(str).to_s #=> #<MatchData "A"> i.e. just "A"

str.scan(/\w+/)       #=> ["A", "man", "a", "plan", "a", "canal", "Panama"]
```

The methods should bring the same result, shouldn't they?

Comment: You're not showing any research effort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`match` will only returns the first match, because that's what it does, while `scan` will return all matches. The regexes used do actually work exactly the same. [See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993662/whats-the-difference-between-scan-and-match-on-ruby-string)